# Initial Value Default for Generic with a Generic Type

Tags: vhdl

I'm pretty sure this cannot be done in VHDL 2008. I wondered if it will be possible in VHDL 2019.

I want to provide an initial value to a generic where the type is a generic type in the same interface list.

```
generic (
  type some_type;
  G_INIT : some_type; --I want this to default to the initial value of some_type
)

...

signal s : some_type := G_INIT;
```

Ideally, I would want it to simply default to the initial value of the type,  But the user could override it if they wish. You cannot use any of the standard attributes because you don't know if `some_type` will be a scalar, discrete or composite type. In the above with 2008, The only option appears to be to force the user to provide a value for `G_INIT` every time.

Ideally, there would be an attribute such as `T'INITIAL_VAL` to cover this.

Comment: I suspect that your generic list could also include a function (perhaps called INITIAL_VAL) that returns the initial value that you want.

Comment: OTOH, if you do not default map the function most of the time then you may as well map the constant value instead.

Comment: A [mcve] demonstrating a failure is important here. The only operations predefined for an interface type are (6.5.3) Interface type declarations assignment, allocation, type qualification, type conversion and (=) and  (/=) operators implicitly declared. That naturally leads to the idea of including an initialization function as Jim comments. it's actual can be changed. Otherwise [G_INIT will require a generic map association](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxWea.jpg) (6.5.6.2 Generic clauses, including -2019 "It is an error if no actual is specified for a given formal generic constant...").

Comment: @user1155120 It wasnt really a question of failure. More of convenience. if `some_type => std_logic`, then the user has to assign `G_INIT=> std_logic'left` . If `some_type => my_crazy_record_type`, then the user either has to build a complex constant, or connect it to a signal (for the initial value). Neither seems ideal

Comment: Using a function as @JimLewis suggest, also requires the user to define a function for every type they want to use in the generic map.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't well suited for _implied_ hypothetical questions without showing research effort and limiting the question to a specific problem. Note some_type could be associated with an unbounded array subtype (e.g. bit_vector with no constraint). Object declaration subtype indications can supply constraints to aggregate initial value expressions. Unbounded array type declarations can't. Subtype by itself isn't a universal glue for an initial expression, an initial value is associated with an object declaration. (5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1 General, 6.4.2 Object declarations).

Comment: @user1155120 That is a very good point, meaning G_INIT couldnt really be used at all in those circumstances. I guess while you've lost some convienience and (and potentially functionality), you gain with huge flexability.

Comment: In any event it explains why a T'DEFAULT_INITIALVALUE isn't there (scalar types use T'LEFT) and O'INIT_VAL would require additional simulation kernel storage for object representations and couldn't be updated nor used during an object's declaration (prior to elaboration). (And isn't in -2019.)